# Ethtool counters are different on different servers even though ethtool version is same. Why?

Tags: linux, suse

I have two servers running same version of ethtool (2.6.39). However when I run ethtool -S eth0 on these servers, I noticed the counter names shown are all different.
One server show RX_OVERSIZE_PACKETS and the other server show RX_OVER_ERRORS.

May I know why the counter names are different even though the version is the same ?

Comment: Because the ethernet cards -and drivers- are different.

Answer (score 0):

Ethtool is ultimately designed to let you poke at network drivers form shell scripts or interactively.  Because of this it provides the bare minimum necessary to expose data from the various calls it makes into the networking drivers, and is as a result extremely dependent on the networking drivers themselves for what functionality it provides.

In your case, it looks like you've got two different ethernet cards, and possibly different drivers, and the particular command you used with ethtool doesn't normalize field names across drivers.